# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

I am getting error " Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client".Please help me.When I try the same thing on postman it works fine.

```
const express = require("express");
const https = require("https");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/",function(req,res){
  const apiKey="ae148f2088da42d7a47ac8e44a4a2768";
  const url="https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey="+apiKey;
  https.get(url,function(response){
    response.on("data",function(data){
      const news=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
      res.send("news data"+news);
    })
  })
})
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `data` event fires whenever you get some data from the HTTP stream. It will fire **multiple times** until all the data has arrived.

Consequently, with your current code, you are calling `send` multiple times for each request.

You need to store that data somewhere (e.g. concatenating it in a variable) and then only do something with it when the `end` event fires.

---

A better approach might be to stop using the built-in `https` module and use something with a more modern design (such as Axios).

Comment: I am a newbie.I tried writing the code like this using axios:  axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    console.log(response.data);
  }); I get error UnhandledPromiseRejectionwarning.Please help me

Comment: I get error UnhandledPromiseRejectionwarning Error: Request failed with status code 426.Please help me

Answer (score -1):

This is the answer for the question.The problem is solved

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const axios=require("axios");
const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.get("/",async function(req,res){
  const apiKey="ae148f2088da42d7a47ac8e44a4a2768";
 const url="http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&category=business&apiKey=ae148f2088da42d7a47ac8e44a4a2768";
   await axios.get(url)
  .then((response) => {
    const d=response.data.articles[0].source.id;
    res.send(d);
  }) .catch((error) =>{
    console.log(error);
  })
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server started on port 3000");
});
```